# Facebook Instant Articles Video not playing

Tags: facebook, video, iframe, facebook-iframe, facebook-instant-articles

I am embbed a video in my artcile as follows:  `<figure class="op-interactive">
  <iframe class="column-width" src="https://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=xxxxxxxx&amp;keepEmbedCode=true" width="320" height="180"></iframe>
</figure>`  I am embedding this right after the end of the `<header>` tag.

When I browse to the video URL, the video loads and plays.  However, when viewing the article from my instant articles library using my iPhone 6s Plus, I just see a small circle where the video is supposed to be and it doesn't play.  I tried a different combination embedding this video per the FB instant articles documentation to no avail.  Am i doing anything wrong.

Comment: iPhone doesn’t support flash (at least not natively), so you can’t expect videos that are embedded via a flash player only to work.

Comment: @CBroe, the same video is embedded in a website article (non-instant article) and when I open the web page via my iPhone, the video plays.  What is the difference, do you know?